# Check if inserted row is the same as current

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a table named **ticket**. I get the data of all tickets from another base and put it in mine with simple Insert.

By clicking a button on my website, I want the user to be able to update the tickets. Basically I would like to do all these points without making too much code :

- The new tickets that are not already in my base will be inserted
- The tickets already inserted which data is not up to date will be updated
- The tickets already inserted which data is up to date will be ignored

By now, I've tried to make a trigger which looks like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER before_insert_task BEFORE INSERT
ON ticket FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE ticket
    SET technician = NEW.technician,
    date = NEW.date,
    closeDate = NEW.closeDate,
    solution = NEW.solution,
    content = NEW.content,
    actiontime = NEW.actiontime;
END
```

This does not work, I saw that you cant make trigger that update before/after insert.

Comment: In my opinion, trigger is not best approach for your problem. trigger is use to do different task before/after insert or update, example like sumOfOrder will increase if we submit new item etc etc. for your problem i suggest stored procedure to check record first with "Select" and do the logic operation like the requirement. :)

Comment: Any reason a simple [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replace.html) won't suffice?

Comment: Did you try this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: I don't know a lot about procedures, I will check this.
I will also try `ON DUPLICATE KEY`, it looks like adapted to me.
Thanks guys